# What is the process through which transactions and transaction receipts are found on a Ethereum database

Tags: transactions, database, merkle-patricia-tries, receipts, leveldb

Transactions and transaction receipts are constructed into Merkle Patricia Tries using the rlp encoded index with which they appear in a block.  Once all tx information is rlp & hex prefix encoded a hash is generated to use as the key in a key value store such as leveldb or rocksdb. If the look up isn't the transaction hash itself (but a hash of more complex info), what is the underlying process through which transactions and receipts are located?

Or more plainly if you call **ethersjs** `provider.getTransaction( hash )` or alternatively for example you make the rpc call `eth_getTransactionReceipt` passing a tx hash what are the steps for locating this data on a trie backed by levelDB?